# PHP/MYSQL - User Photos Prev/Next link

Tags: php, image, navigation, hyperlink

My project has User accounts which has Photos that belong to each User that has uploaded them

Id like to show a next and previous photo for each user, so when I go to a friends list of photos I can navigate (Obviously) to the users next uploaded photo. I would be fine with these being the next/previous photo in photo_id order.

How would you write that kind of query for one next / previous photo?

My table structure is like so.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userphotos` (
  `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `photo_ownerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photo_ispublic` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photo_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `photo_caption` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `photo_imagedata` longblob NOT NULL,
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`photo_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=89 ;
```

Would I use something like this to select the id's

PREVIOUS IMAGE

```
SELECT field1 FROM tablename WHERE id < $currentid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

NEXT IMAGE

```
SELECT field1 FROM tablename WHERE ID > $currentid ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I suggest you run an Internet search on `PHP image gallery`.  You can save yourself many hours.

Comment: I already have user albums which show individual photos. But would just like to implement the navigation to complete the last few steps I would like to undertake. Next few would be 'Download Image' 'Share Image' And 'Modify Image'.

I am looking around the net as we speak for examples to see what I need to do. Would be great for someone to explain in depth so I have a clearer understanding. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those queries should work for what you want to accomplish. Though you should also add the owner id to limit photos that will be browsed to those owned by the user.

**Previous Image**

```
SELECT field1 FROM tablename 
WHERE id < $currentId AND photo_ownerid = $ownerId 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Next Image**

```
SELECT field1 FROM tablename 
WHERE ID > $currentId AND photo_ownerid = $ownerId 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

However, as hinted in a comment to the question, there are more efficient alternatives over querying the database everytime you wish to view the next/previous photo. You can for instance query all the photos at once then use a javascript library, [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) for instance, to neatly organize and navigate through the photos.

Comment: Thank you for your advise Varchair. It was very helpul. :D

Comment: So when I query all the photos and the then use a javascript Library. Would I query all by selecting the users album!

My album is
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `albums` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_public` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;`